# Revert Changes in sandbox org

Tags: contact, data

While working on a functionality I updated all the contact names in my org with a particular name. Can I revert back all the changes and get back the previous contacts? If so, how?

Comment: Do you have field history tracking enabled? Otherwise you would have to resort to whatever backups you made before you made this change. If you don't have any backups, then it's a learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this. There isn't a backup that Salesforce provides that allows you to restore data.

Now if you did have field history tracking set up on the Name field within the Contact object, it's possible to write a bit of Apex to find the "Old" values and update the Contact record with them.